# Accessing IP from MySQL with PHP and updating it

Tags: php, mysql

When I update from PHP code my DB table based on any column name(id, username, whatever) - everything goes well. But if I try to update it based on an IP - it fails.

I store the IP as varchar(39) and using MySQL.

Perhaps someone here would know why is it can't access(update) it based on IP?

Thanks

Update:

The schema of the table is very simple, it contains:

|id|userid|username|ip|date

The code is coming from class to class... I tried to use it as best as I could with OOP with lots of helpers. But the main point is that it works great, but not with the IPs...

By googling I found out ip2long function, so it's probably something related to the issue.

Update 2:

```
+----------+-------------+------+-----+
| Field    | Type        | Null | Key | 
+----------+-------------+------+-----+
| id       | int(11)     | NO   | PRI |
| userid   | int(11)     | NO   |     | 
| username | varchar(20) | NO   |     |
| ip       | varchar(39) | NO   |     |
| date     | datetime    | NO   |     |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+-
```

Made it by hand :) No idea what should be the datetime exactly

Comment: If you want an answer, you might edit your question and include the schema of the table, and the PHP code you are using to update the table. Also, any error messages the code is showing.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We are a community of volunteers offering aid to programmers stuck on a 
particular task. We are not a service to write free code for you. Please read 
[What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and 
[How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thanks Sloan, but I have no means for you to code something for me. I just want to know if there's something special with comparing and updating IPs from PHP in the MySQL

Comment: That 2nd comment isn't intended to chastise you, but to provide some useful links that will show you how to ask a question here on SO. Re-read the first comment and update your question accordingly.

Comment: BTW, a *schema* will show the full definition of the table, not just column names. It will show the column definitions, indexes, etc. Most people just post the *CREATE TABLE* statement used to define the table.

Comment: I didn't realize the schema is a real thing. Googling it...

Comment: have you checked your update code directly in mysql for testing?

Comment: Robert, do you mean after I execute my PHP script? Yes, sure... it doesn't update. It throw new Exception() error

Comment: How can we help you if you dont show the code updating your IP ?

Comment: Please show the code. then only we can help you